# Shop does not work in Wordpress Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, slug, permalinks

I am confused with this error, because I am not really sure how to debug it.

I have setup my .htaccess file and set my Permalinks to Custom Structure:

```
/%category%/
```

I have also tried

```
/%postname%/
```

and

```
/%category%//%postname%/
```

None of these worked.

All links work correctly, except for Shop, which throws a 404. If I override the slug to shop-1, it works.

Is there a Permalink conflict with the slug "shop"? That does not seem likely, as it works on my local machine, just not on the prod server.

Here is my .htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I will be glad to post any other code or necessary information. I am just not sure what you might need to diagnose this issue.

Non Default plugins include:

NivoSlider plugin 
W3 Total Cache

It still happens when I deactivate these plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "Redirection" or any similar plugins?  If so you might clear the redirection log there and try again.

Otherwise, you could check for a conflicting slug in other term areas such as tags and get rid of those.

Comment: Added plugins to the question. I do not see any conflicting tags. When I override the slug to "shop" in the Pages section, I do not get an auto-incremented number. This makes me think it is available. Not sure though...